# SwiftUI: PrivacySensitive doesn't work for iOS16

Tags: swiftui

I would like to redact a text on my widget when the device is locked. The below code works when I test it on iOS15, but didn't work on iOS16.

```
struct WidgetView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some sensitive text")
            .privacySensitive()
    }
}
```

Above applies to testing on both simulator and actual devices. I use xcode 14.2

Answer (score 0):

Before iOS16, the  `.privacySensitive()` was used to protect the sensitive data. Later, instead of `.privacySensitive()` apple has introduced `.redacted(reason: .placeholder)` or `.redacted(reason: .privacy)` to protect sensitive data.

You can try the code mentioned below, It will help you. Instead of `1234 5678 9012 3456` it will show placeholder.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Card number")
            Text("1234 5678 9012 3456")
                .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
        }
    }
}
```